# Alter User Identified By Inquiry

Tags: oracle, change-password

Inquiring if the statement after identified by is the password 'pw12334' to be applied to the account
example
Alter user username identified by pw1234 account unlock.

also inquiring if "identfied by" command alone can replace password without the "replace" command

kinda confused here, since I need to apply the password to apex.xml to make the ords 503 error go away.

Comment: What is the "replace" command - I never heard of it. Do you mean the "alter" command? If you do, then the answer is NO; "identified by" is a **clause** in the "alter user" command, it is not a stand-alone **command**. And indeed, the word right after "identified by" is the (new) password for that user.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax to unlock the user is, the IDENTIFIED BY password is needed becuase  if you unlock an account without resetting the password then the password remains expired.

```
 ALTER USER james IDENTIFIED BY Jim123 ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```